# Compiling gitsh for windows

Tags: c, windows, git, thoughtbot

[gitsh](https://github.com/thoughtbot/gitsh) is an interesting tool from [Thoughtbot](https://thoughtbot.com/).

Unfortunately, their package is not available for Windows.

I am trying to compile it on Windows with great difficulties.

After resolving many dependency related errors, I'm facing the following error:

```
depbase=`echo src/gitsh.o | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.o$||'`;\
        gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"gitsh\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"gitsh\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.11.1\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"gitsh\ 0.11.1\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"hello@thoughtbot.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"gitsh\" -DVERSION=\"0.11.1\" -I.  -DGITSH_RB_PATH="\"/usr/local/share/gitsh/ruby/gitsh.rb\"" -I/c/dev/readline/include/  -g -O2 -MT src/gitsh.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o src/gitsh.o src/gitsh.c &&\
        mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
src/gitsh.c:1:17: fatal error: err.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/gitsh.o] Error 1
```

From what I found out, I think these libraries don't exist for Windows.

Can anyone suggest me a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you building on windows? Cygwin?

Comment: Yes. But using Git-bash & Ruby Devkit

Comment: gitsh is pretty dependent on a bunch of Unix environment stuff, including compile time things like `err.h`, and runtime things like tput(1). I don't know how many of those things are available on Windows. I maintain gitsh, and I'd welcome pull requests to add Windows support, but I'm unlikely to add it myself.